# XML deserialization ignores one element

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an XSD describing my XML document.  From this XSD i have generated classes using XSD.exe.

I have an XML document of about 3800 lines (about 150KB).

In a web service I read the document and deserialize it into the class generated form the XSD. Detailed inspection revealed that ONE element is not deserialized (instance is null).

I added the event handlers to catch unknown element, unknown attribute, unknown nodes, and unreferenced objects.

The reader throws an "Unknown node" and "Unknown Attribute" on this line:

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.navicure.com/Transaction" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.navicure.com/Transaction Transaction.xsd">
```

Both of which point to the "xsi:schemaLocation" attribute — which seems to be erroneous.  No other events are thrown.

I have been unable to get the debugger to step into the deserialization logic to see what's going on when it gets to that element.

Any suggestions on how to shed light on the cause of this deserialization issue?

Comment: that schemaLocation seems invalid... should there be a slash instead of a space there?  Is that something that you are providing manually, or depending on third-party code?

Comment: Make sure in the class the property is public.  private properties to not get serialized.

Comment: the property is public - the XSD.exe generated code made that correctly.

Comment: I reckon we need to see a [mcve] to help you.  For instance. here's an example of your XML being deserialized and re-serialized successfully:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/OjfW2z